# How to consume a netstandard2.0 assembly using VS 2015 (in a 4.6.2 library)?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-standard-2.0

Alternative Title: **Is everything older than VS2017.3 deprecated?**

I have this single netstandard 2.0 assembly which I have to consume from within an 4.6.2 class library using VS2015(.3).

But this does not compile, I always get:

> error MC1000: Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to
>   assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' because it has not been preloaded.

I installed the NuGet Package `NETStandard.Library` and also tried `ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades=false` -- did not change anything.

---

Update:

Now this MC1000 hit me again in another solution where absolutely nothing has to do with netstandard: Everything is using NET 4.6.2.
I just did nothing more than applying suggested NuGet package updates:

Before:

```
  <package id="System.Reflection.TypeExtensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
```

After:

```
  <package id="System.Reflection.TypeExtensions" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net462" />
```

Exact same error message as above. IMHO according to SemVer such thing should not happen from 4.3.0 to 4.4.0.

Once again I tried if installing NETStandard.Library NuGet package helped, but did not.

The .NET core 2.0 SDK is installed on this machine. NuGet package managers version is 3.6.0.2511 as suggested by https://blog.nuget.org/20170815/Whats-nu-in-NuGet-with-VS2017-15-3.html

Comment: How did you manage to get past the error?

Comment: @Purusartha I installed VS 2017 (and even there ServicePack 3+ was needed)

Comment: I was getting this error as I was trying to open the solution in vs2015

Comment: @Purusartha I'm sorry, I gave up using VS2015 (hence the alternative subject) and installed VS2017 to get rid of all that shit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your NuGet client to a minimum version of 3.6.

See section Tooling Prerequisistes,
https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/24

Nuget download link:
https://www.nuget.org/downloads

Comment: In my case I had to update from 4.1.0 to 5.x.x in our Azure DevOps server. Our build agent folders each contained two nuget.exe files. We updated them both. Problem solved.